# Regex for matching email adress to domain

Tags: c#, regex

Given I have the domain pattern of

```
domain.com
sub.domain.com
*.com
*.domain.com
sub.*.com
```

Given I will have email address in the format of

```
user@domain.com
user@sub.domain.com
```

Is it possible to make 1 regex pattern to find if the email address matches one of the domain pattern?

Comment: `*.com` will include all other doamins. So why you want other domains to be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this in the end

```
myPattern.Replace("*", myPattern.StartsWith("*") ? "@[A-Za-z0-9]+" : "[A-Za-z0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, *.com include all of other patterns. You can check if emails `endwith` `.com` is enough for you

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>
                      {
                          "a@domain.com",
                          "a@sub.domain.com",
                          "a@asd.com",
                          "a@.sub.asdas.com",
                          "a@.sub.asdas.com",
                      };

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(domain\.com)|(sub\.*\.com)");

emails= emails.Where(e => regex.IsMatch(e)).ToList();
```

If you want to check multiple patterns with regex, you can use `|`

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>
                      {
                          "a@domain.com",
                          "a@sub.domain.com",
                          "a@asd.com",
                          "a@.sub.asdas.com",
                          "a@.sub.asdas.com",
                      };

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(domain.com)|(sub.*.com)");

emails= emails.Where(e => regex.IsMatch(e)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?[a-zA-Z]+.)?(provider1|provider2).(domain1|domain2)$

Tried this regex with this example : abc123@provider1.domain1 - is valid

regex for emails with sub domain :

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?[a-zA-Z]+.)?(sub1|sub2).(provider1|provider2).(domain1|domain2)$

It will work with any domain and mail service provider. I have tried this and it works

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex.  Can be done with linq :

```
            string[] domains = { "*.sub.domain.com", "*.com", "*.domain.com", "sub.*.com" };

            string email = "abc.sub.domain.com";
            string user = "abc";

            bool match = domains.Any(x => x.Replace("*", user) == email);
```